# Translating a surname to English - a tough one

Tags: translation, surnames

Hello Ladies and Gents!

This has been bothering me for the last couple of years. When I was 16-17y old I had a problem with explaining my US/UK friends how to pronounce my surname  - "Wieczorek". After few failed attempts I decided I should look it up in dictionary and find the translation.

The word "Wieczorek" im my language (polish) means the diminutivation of word "Evening". It's not said if it's "Soiree" kind of evening or not - it's the word just by itself. And it doesn't sound like diminutive, actually it sounds pretty hard.

So my question is: is it ok to use the word "Soiree"? I mean, does it sounds ok? Have You ever heard this surname in english spoken countries?

(Ofc I'm not talking about using it officially ;) )

Regards,
Paul

Comment: I'm not sure many people in the US would be able to pronounce it any better than "Wieczorek".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about foreign proper nouns, not English

Comment: My suggestion. Don't worry about it. Keep your name as is. Not everyone will pronounce your name correctly at first try. It's okay.

Comment: The dictionaries I consulted suggest that the surname Wieczorek should be understood not as "little evening" but as "little evening creature", *viz* a flittermouse. If you want to pun on your name I suggest you introduce yourself by saying "I'm Batman".

Comment: Certainly if you simply want a nickname then "Woz" would be readily accepted, as would "Wiz" (or "Whiz").  And you might even want to consider "Wize".

Comment: @StoneyB You should change Your dictionary, my friend. Little evening creature? What the hell? Congrats to the guy who created this one.

Comment: @HotLicks Actually... It's not a bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

'Soiree' sounds unnatural. Don't change your name. There are others with your last name, like a professor at Stanford University, and a politician in New Hampshire. Just be proud of your name. I'm proud of mine, and mine isn't so easy either.

Comment: Cathy, thank You for the answer. I didn't want to literally change my surname, just need to use some kind of alternative in domain name for example because I really doubt anyone would remember how to write "Wieczorek" in adress bar if they don't have my business card. I'm really proud of my name because of the things my dad done :)

Comment: @psoiree    You could shorten it to Wiec - what do you think? That's pronounceable.